# Efficient work with large amounts of sounds

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I am working on an android app that enables users to play short (~3 sec on average, 10 sec is the absolute maximum) audio clips (most likely format will be mp3) when they e.g. tap on a button. There will be around 10 sets of these sounds, each set will have around 100 sounds. It is sufficient if only one sound is playing at any time. The sounds are not played in a particular order, so we can never know which sound will play next. The user can change the set of sounds that are playing at any time.

My question is how to efficiently implement the playback of such audio clips. The current (naive and not efficient) implementation uses a `MediaPlayer` which loads each sound when it should be played, plays it, and then releases it. This is terrible, since `MediaPlayer` is supposed to be used with longer sound files. Each sound is loaded on demand, so no pre-loading is occurring. There are slight delays when playing the sound, due to the loading taking place right after user interaction, and the playing has to wait for the load.

Some possibilities that I thought of:

1. Use `SoundPool` and load on demand. Whenever we load a sound, implement the actual playback in an `OnLoadCompleteListener`, and free once the sound finishes. This is similar to the current implementation, but uses a `SoundPool`. Alternatively, do not release immediately, but only when the sets are exchanged.
2. Use `MediaPlayer` and compact all the sound files (with short silence to separate the sounds) into one longer mp3, and use `seekTo()` to get to the right time in the audio clip. The actual playing of the sound would occur in an `OnSeekCompleteListener`, which would resume from the time we jumped to, play exactly for how long the sound is, and then pause. This would require some pre-processing before throwing the longer sound in the app, like compressing all the sounds into one file and then storing offsets and lengths in the database. The one longer sound (representing the whole set of sounds) would be pre-loaded asynchronously.
3. Use `SoundPool` like in approach 1, but pre-load (asynchronously of course) the whole set of sounds we might be using (~100 sounds). When the user presses a button, we just check if the sound had already been loaded into the sound pool, and if not, waits until the loading completes. When the user would switch the set of sounds, all loaded sounds are discarded and the asynchronous load for the next set of sounds starts. I am afraid that waiting for the load might cause delays, which we want to reduce as much as possible (ofc).

The question is, which of these approaches would be the most efficient. I am particularly afraid that there might be some problems with approaches 2 and 3, like seeking taking too long, or pre-loading taking too long for lots of small files.

I hope I made everything clear. Does anyone have experience with the approaches I presented here? What do you think (or better, know) will be the best approach. Thanks for the answers.